# Problem with Ultimate Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to install ultimate skyrim and am having trouble with one of the steps. I've been able to install everything except DynDOLOD Resources. It's keeping me from completing my install. Any suggestions?

I tried renaming the 7z file to match that in Automaton, but that didn't work.

When I click on the AutoDownloader slider, I get this:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is. Why can't you install dyndolod resources? Are you getting an error of some kind?

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas No error at all, which is what makes it so frustrating. Everything else installs fine. I've tried downloading it manually and copying it into the mods folder, but that doesn't work. The US installer seems to depend on everything being nice and cozy and installed, so I can't go forward.

Comment: It may be worth also asking on the Ultimate Skyrim Reddit page, as well as the Ultimate Skyrim discord. I believe they do have a support channel there. (Cannot link to them right now, will later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the US downloader was looking for a version of that mod that's no longer available. Someone on the US reddit linked it and everything went fine.